# Setting Formatter or FormatterFactory for JFormattedTextField still doesn't restrict the characters I type to the format I define

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a Renderer class that extends `JFormattedTextField`

In its constructor I set up Formatter and FormatterFactory in order to pass the input format limitations, but still have ability to input characters of wrong format, not the restricted one

```
NumberFormat bigDecimalFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    bigDecimalFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(1);
    bigDecimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
    bigDecimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    NumberFormatter numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(bigDecimalFormat);
    numberFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
    numberFormatter.setValueClass(BigDecimal.class);
    numberFormatter.setMinimum(0.0);
    numberFormatter.setMaximum(1.0);
    //numberFormatter.setFormat(new DecimalFormat("#.####")); //tried to enable and disable it, but that doesn't help
    this.setFormatter(numberFormatter);
    this.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(numberFormatter));
```

and it is still possible to enter a text like 11.111.111, thet it gots exception on converting that to `BigDecimal`

In all explanations setting Formatter is enough, however, they use to do it through the constructor parameter, not the setter like me. What is the working way, if I extend the `JFormattedTextField`  and need to set up the format in the constructor and want to limit the typed characters to the desired format only?

[image]

Comment: What behavior are you expecting?  If you really want to force every keystroke the user enters to be immediately disallowed if the resulting text would be an invalid value, you can do that with [setAllowsInvalid(false)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/DefaultFormatter.html#setAllowsInvalid(boolean)), but you really shouldn’t.  Doing so would prevent users from performing intermediate edits;  for example, I might want to type or paste `1.5`, then press the ‘←’ key twice and delete the `1`.  Don’t punish a user before they’re finished typing!

Comment: @VGR i have already setAllowsInvalid(false), but it looks like the field is ignorant to this property

Comment: @VGR the only thing I want is to allow the text, matching the specific mask as the result. Which approach should be used for thst?

Comment: I think you just need to use a [MaskFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#maskformatter), as in: `JFormattedTextField ftf = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("#.####"));`